# Found multiple catalogs matching schema when running mvn liquibase:diff to update database

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster, liquibase

I'm using JHipster. When I add a new entity and run

```
mvn -e compile liquibase:diff
```

I get the following Error:

> Error setting up or running Liquibase:
>   liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException:
>   liquibase.snapshot.InvalidExampleException: Found multiple catalogs
>   matching schema -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.3:diff
>   (default-cli) on project schema: Error setting up or running
>   Liquibase: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException:
>   liquibase.snapshot.InvalidExampleException: Found multiple catalogs
>   matching schema

I am using MySQL 5.7 as the DBMS

Comment: It can be related to the following bug https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3271

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say given the lack of details (what database are you using?) But I would guess that perhaps the database allows for names that differ in case only (schemaOne vs schemaone vs SCHEMAONE).